# Separating columns in Power BI based on data type

Tags: xml, powerbi

I'm brand new to Power BI and I'm pulling an xml file from my companies site that is created from database records. I'm trying to get two columns, one with the integers, and one with the dates so I can make a line graph. Here's the column it's pulling now:

[Value file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Bku.jpg)

And here's the XML file:

```xml
    <RECORDS>
    <COUNT>20</COUNT>
    <DISPLAY_LIST_START>1</DISPLAY_LIST_START>
    <DISPLAY_LIST_STOP>20</DISPLAY_LIST_STOP>
    <STOP>20</STOP>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/01/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>5</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/02/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/03/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>2</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/06/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[2.5]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/05/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>2</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/08/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>6</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/09/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>5</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/10/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>5</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/11/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>5</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/12/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>4</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/15/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[4.5]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/16/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[4.5]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/21/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>6</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/22/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>2</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/24/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/25/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/26/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>4</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/27/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/29/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>5</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <SESSION_ID>OGYkhXOUbcnefM6RZkvRHUipY3QIiX64bPTKRmOz</SESSION_ID>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE><![CDATA[06/30/2020]]></VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD>
    <VALUE>5</VALUE>
    </FIELD>
    </RECORD>
    </RECORDS>
```

Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: what does the xml file look like?

Comment: I added it to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the xml is not the best, but I guess you cannot have it changed.  Here's what you could do:

1. add a index column BEFORE you expand the RECORD.FIELD column.  Like this you have some row number to group the rows together later.
2. after you expand the column RECORD.FIELD you can add a custom column with a formula to check if the value is numeric or not (or a date or not).
3. Based on this custom column, you can pivot the table.

Here is the result in the M language (advanced editor)

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("D:\temp\stack.xml")),
    Table0 = Source{0}[Table],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table0,{{"COUNT", Int64.Type}, {"DISPLAY_LIST_START", Int64.Type}, {"DISPLAY_LIST_STOP", Int64.Type}, {"STOP", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Expanded RECORD" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "RECORD", {"SESSION_ID", "FIELD"}, {"RECORD.SESSION_ID", "RECORD.FIELD"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded RECORD", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Expanded RECORD.FIELD" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Index", "RECORD.FIELD", {"VALUE"}, {"RECORD.FIELD.VALUE"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded RECORD.FIELD", "Custom", each try ( 
    if Value.Is( Number.FromText( [RECORD.FIELD.VALUE])  ,Number.Type) 
    then "num" 
    else "nonum"
    )
otherwise "nonum"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"RECORD.FIELD.VALUE", "Index", "Custom"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"[Custom]), "Custom", "RECORD.FIELD.VALUE", List.Min)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thank you! Where did you pick this stuff up? I'd like to gain some skill with this in case I need maintenance on this data.

Comment: I have no idea about M syntax, for the date check in the custom column I put 
```
    if( try Date.ToText([RECORD.FIELD.VALUE], "dd-mm-yyyy") 
````
But i'm not sure how to put it into a new column or if this will even work

Comment: you don't really have to write the M code yourself, just let power bi generate it for you.  But it can give you a good idea on how to do it.

Comment: So I don't need a formula in the custom column? Is the code you posted generated by Power BI?